# C# how to retrieve the generic type from container?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a composite pattern, which use generics to have type info in the list, so its not just objects.

```
interface IA {
  string name{get;set;}
}

class B<T>:IA {
  T value{get;set;}
}

class C:B<IList<IA>> {
  add(IA obj){...};
  remove(IA obj){..}
}
```

Which Works nicely when I build the manage the tree of data.
My problem is how do I retrieve the objects in the composite,
and how should I retrieve their type, so I can use that information to build logic with.
I need it to choose what GUI I should present, how I should store it in XML etc..
thanks in advance..

Comment: Where's the composite pattern? Your `C` class doesn't implement `IA` interface. Also, I don't think `C:B<IList<IA>>` is valid C# and `B` doesn't provide any implementation of the interface member.

Comment: you can retrieve the type like you always do in C#. Use `.GetType()` ... the implementation of `add(IA obj)` and `remove(IA obj)` is redundant and unsafe sice u can't be sure that `T` in class `B` will be `IList<IA>`...